# Tell Wildfly to redirect to HTTPS after login instead of HTTP when behind HTTPS wildfly undertow-balancer

Tags: redirect, https, jboss7.x, undertow, wildfly-12

We have a load-balancer sitting in front of two wildfly servers. The load-balancer handles the SSL handshake and forces all traffic over https (http requests are redirected to https requests), the wildfly nodes do not have certificates on them and traffic between load balancer and servers is unencrypted, the wildfly nodes know nothing about the SSL.

When a user hits a protected page the wildfly presents them with a login page. User enters credentials and submits the login form. The wildfly logs user in and then sends a redirect to the user to send them to the desired page. The redirect sent by the wildfly is an HTTP redirect. This gets grabbed by the load-balancer and redirected to HTTPS but I really want to avoid that second redirect. How can I tell the wildfly to return HTTPS redirect after login instead of HTTP?

I followed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685181/tell-jboss-as7-to-redirect-to-https-after-login-instead-of-http-when-behind-http) but not sure how to deal same between wildlfy undertow load-balancer and wildfly server.

I followed [this link also](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/279657)  but didn't get any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the detailed solution explanation for the above problem:

We have a load-balancer sitting in front of two wildfly servers. The load-balancer handles the SSL handshake and forces all traffic over https , the wildfly nodes do not have certificates on them and traffic between load balancer and servers is unencrypted, the wildfly nodes know nothing about the SSL.The communication between load balancer and wildfly nodes is via http protocol.

When a user hits a protected page  e.g. https://someip/app

Request flow is as below:

- Client browser to load balancer via https
- Load balancer to wildlfy nodes via http protocol .
- It worked after adding  proxy-address-forwarding="true" in wildlfy server node's  http
  listener .